# Search color from a list in DB , having a pallete

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of color in database (MySQL)from generated from  http://www.coolphptools.com/color_extract , is possible to search , from a pallet of color like in this image  [image]

what will be the query , and how should i keep the list in DB , I'm sorry but actually i have no idea how to manage , to make a list for every image manually is to much job , and it takes time , and is not logical , maybe exist a better way ,

I have a list of templates , and i need to create a search of colors like http://www.templatemonster.com/templates.php  , i need just an idea how to start

THANK YOU A LOT !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Storing it in a database, you could store red green and blue values seperatley with maybe a hex value as a key (or even the rgb values as a composite key)

Then it's up to you to decide what you define as 'close to another colour'  If you mean the average difference in colour in all three colour channels then you will need to construct an sql statement that does precisley that, however there are many definitions of whats 'closest' so it depends very much on your exact situation.

Comment: I have a list of templates , and i need to create a search of colors like http://www.templatemonster.com/templates.php , and i thought that is better to make a list of dominant colors for every template , and than to search throw it

Comment: yeah so having a table with your colours in, with dome sort of id you can reference from your templates table would work fine wouldn't it?  As for closeness of colour, thats for yo to decide how you want to define close.

Comment: i need if searching for gray , just some variation for gray